# Horizontal Scroll View is Hanging and taking time to move

Tags: java, android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have created a `Horizontal Scroll View` and have added multiple `Image Buttons` in it.

Everything seems working fine, but when i run my program in `Genymotion Emulator` its not working properly. When i click and movie `scroll view` it takes lot of time to move.

First i thought that its `Emulator` Problem, but when i deployed `apk` file on my phone, its hanging there as well.

Kindly guide me how to move `Horizontal Scroll View` smoothly.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="200dp"

        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fullSchedule"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newsView"
            android:background="@drawable/fullschedule"

            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/standings"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newsView"
            android:background="@drawable/standings" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
```

Comment: post your java code it seems there is no problem in your layout

Comment: @bryanc: Thanks for reply, my java code is doing a lot of tasks, Its been calling `Async Task` to get data from `json` I have posted a excerpt from my class

Comment: i think your behind tasks are impressive and cause your ui works  slowly . just as a test delete some tasks and run your app to test just layout and then add other tasks